# Structure for storage with pointers to instances of itself - having issues with some data - recursive structure

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, structure, storage

I have the following structure for storing data (kind of sparse octree).
It works fine as long as "if (empty)" part is commented out - but this increases the size of the structure.
If the "if (empty)" is uncommented, it works 95% correctly and the size decreases by at least 4x, but some of the data from Get() is not identical with the data which was set with Set().
I have a hunch it might be due to having a structure of pointers?
I tried a lot of things and I cannot figure this one out. Can anyone see any problems with the "if (empty)" part uncommented? Why would I get some different results?

Regards,

```
struct StorageCtr
{
    bool leaf = true;
    bool empty = true;
    float Data = 0.0f;
    StorageCtr* Child[8] = { NULL,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL }; //Tried nullptr and same effect
    uint8 CurrentLevel;

    StorageCtr(uint8 l)
    {
        CurrentLevel = l;
    }

    void Set(int x, int y, int z, float FloatVal)
    {
        int idx, idy, idz;
        int ChildId;

          /*if (empty) //if this is uncommented, what is stored is not 100% equal to what is retrieved anymore.
            {
                Data = FloatVal; //This would decide what the top level data value is - helps with reducing size of the parent structure.
                empty = false;
                return;
            }*/

        if ((Data == FloatVal) && (leaf == true)) //If data is the same and there is no split, just return - no further action needed
            return;

        if (CurrentLevel > 0) //If any level besides the last one
        {
            idx = (x & (1 << (CurrentLevel - 1))) >> (CurrentLevel - 1);
            idy = (y & (1 << (CurrentLevel - 1))) >> (CurrentLevel - 1);
            idz = (z & (1 << (CurrentLevel - 1))) >> (CurrentLevel - 1);
            ChildId = (idx << 2) | (idy << 1) | idz;

            if (Child[ChildId] == NULL) //If child is null, make a new one and set it. Current is not a leaf anymore.
            {
                Child[ChildId] = new StorageCtr(CurrentLevel - 1);
                Child[ChildId]->Set(x, y, z, FloatVal);
                leaf = false;
            }

            if (Child[ChildId] != NULL) //If child is not null, just set it
            {
                Child[ChildId]->Set(x, y, z, FloatVal);
            }
        }
        else //Last level (0) cannot have children so it gets the Data assigned directly
        {
            Data = FloatVal;
        }
    }

    float Get(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int idx, idy, idz;
        int ChildId;

        if (leaf) //No children, get Data
        {
            return Data;
        }
        else //There are children
        {
            if (CurrentLevel > 0) //Any level besides the last
            {
                idx = (x & (1 << (CurrentLevel - 1))) >> (CurrentLevel - 1);
                idy = (y & (1 << (CurrentLevel - 1))) >> (CurrentLevel - 1);
                idz = (z & (1 << (CurrentLevel - 1))) >> (CurrentLevel - 1);
                ChildId = (idx << 2) | (idy << 1) | idz;
                if (Child[ChildId] != NULL) //If not null, go to Child
                {
                    return (Child[ChildId]->Get(x, y, z)); //If child exists, get the data from child
                }
            }
            return Data; //The child doesn't exist, get data from parent
        }
    }
};
```

It is used by declaring it with:

```
Data_Cont = new StorageCtr(4); //This can store up to 4096 float values. (8^4)
```

Further edit: Here's how I would Get and Set all values:

```
TArray<float> SomeData;
TArray<float> SomeOther;
SomeData.SetNum(16*16*16);
SomeOtherData.SetNum(16*16*16);


//SomeData can be filled with low frequency Perlin noise for example (not shown)


float CurrentValue;

for (int x = 0; x < 16; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <16; ++y)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z <16; ++z)
            {
            CurrentValue= SomeData(x,y,z); //Get CurrentValue from Array
            Data_Cont->Set(x, y, z, CurrentValue); //Write all data to structure
            }
        }
    }
    
    
for (int x = 0; x < 16; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <16; ++y)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z <16; ++z)
            {
            CurrentValue=Data_Cont->Get(x, y, z); //Retrieve all data - CurrentValue from StorageCtr
            SomeOtherData(x,y,z)=CurrentValue; //Receiving array is written
            } 
        }
    }
```

//If you would compare SomeData and SomeOtherData, they won't be 100% identical

Debugging efforts made, that failed:

- setting "nullptr" instead of "NULL"
- commenting / uncommenting the mentioned section of code
- refactoring the Set() and Get() functions in many ways, but ending with same results
- working it out on paper step by step (on smaller size) - cannot see the issue
- searching Google for some days on this issue

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of the failing program. Then tell us what efforts of debugging you have made, what input you use, what output or results you get, and what output or results you expected. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Added reproductible example.

Comment: It seems like you should take this opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger*, and use it to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, to see what happens and when and where things start to go wrong.

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. A reproducible example is something you can copy, paste, save, compile, and run, with no steps in between. If it doesn't have `main()` it cannot be a reproducible example.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate your comments but, this is as much as I can share on the issue - this is part of a much larger and complex program. But this is the part that gives me headaches,: commenting and un-commenting the mentioned part of code. If this is not good enough to get help, I am okay to withdraw the question. Thanks!

Comment: You might also consider using static analysis tools on your code, as well as memory debuggers like Valgrind, possible built-in sanitizers of your compiler, building and testing with and without optimizations, and even building with other compilers. If optimized versus unoptimized behavior differ, or if building with different compilers causes different behavior, then you probably have some *undefined behavior* in your code. Sanitizers, debuggers, compiler warnings, and static analyzers are the tools to help you find such problems.

Comment: Also note that possible undefined behavior might happen almost anywhere in your code, far from the place where it manifests. With that said, the first thing you should add is array bounds checking. For example use `std::array` instead of C-style array, and use the bounds-checked `at` access function to get elements. That will throw an exception if the array is accessed out of bounds.

Comment: `16^3` is 19, not 4096. Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: 16^3 corrected to 16*16*16. It was a typo. Actual assignment in the code is with multiplication.

Comment: Suppose you call  `Set(0,0,0,100)`.  Then you call `Set(0,0,1,200)`. How do you plan to retrieve `100` ever again?

Comment: Thank you very much! I do see now a problem in my logic, as this will clearly not function correctly: if you call Set(0,0,0,100) and Set(0,0,1,200) followed by Get(0,0,0) and Get(0,0,1), both will return 200 .. thanks! I would have never seen it, as I was looking in the wrong place.